# How to input in python multiple times, given 'n' and n inputs line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, integer

The first line gives  `n`, the number of integers in the next line.
Then `n` integers  are given .

My problem is how to accept the inputs, I tried using

```
ab = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

But no use.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

The format of input is:

```
409        //this is n

1 4 6 7 9 11 12 13 16 18 19 21 23 24 32 35 39 41 43 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 60 61 63 64 69 72 73 74 82 85 86 91 94 97 99 100 104 106 110 112 115 117 120 121 123 126 130 131 134 137 138 142 143 144 145 150 151 152 156 157 158 162 165 170 171 172 173 180 181 183 188 191 192 194 196 199 201 202 205 208 212 214 216 219 220 225 227 235 240 243 244 245 246 247 251 252 253 257 258 261 269 270 271 274 276 277 278 285 286 288 291 293 297 301 302 303 304 310 311 316 318 319 321 322 323 327 329 331 332 346 347 349 350 353 356 357 358 362 363 373 376 379 381 384 386 388 390 391 392 394 398 402 403 404 407 412 413 414 416 417 418 421 422 425 428 429 431 433 436 437 438 442 443 444 451 453 459 461 466 473 478 481 483 484 486 487 504 508 513 514 515 520 521 524 527 531 535 537 538 540 541 544 546 549 550 551 554 555 556 557 560 561 562 566 572 574 575 577 583 587 589 592 593 595 596 597 598 600 603 604 606 611 612 616 626 627 629 631 637 638 639 641 644 645 646 647 648 650 652 654 659 660 661 664 665 666 668 669 672 673 677 679 681 683 685 686 688 693 699 701 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 715 717 719 724 725 727 729 730 733 735 736 737 738 739 740 746 747 755 759 761 764 766 767 770 772 773 775 776 780 782 783 788 790 792 793 796 797 798 799 808 814 821 822 825 828 838 843 855 856 861 862 869 871 872 877 884 885 887 890 891 893 894 895 897 901 902 903 908 915 916 918 919 921 922 923 924 928 929 932 934 935 937 938 950 958 959 961 962 967 969 971 972 973 976 978 979 980 982 983 985 988 989 990 991 992 995 998 999
```

Comment: "But no use." Could you be more specific? What error did you get? Or what did the output look like, if it wasn't what you were expecting?

Comment: Also, please clarify whether there's actually an extra blank line between the line containing `n` and the line containing the list of values.

Comment: This isn't a question for just Python but for all languages because your question is purely semantic...you provide us with no effort to write code that you submit for us to examine.  An attempt to research your question, write the code for your solution, and a complete explanation of your situation is required.  BTW:  If somebody writes your code for you the least you can do is to ACCEPT their answer.

Comment: 'But no use' actually means I got a runtime error @glibdud

Comment: @Rahuldubey Could you edit the full traceback into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newline character matters.

```
n = input()
input()  # skip 2nd line
ab = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(n)
print(ab)
```

Comment: Thanks @damians, I was missing the map, Can you please clarify what is map used for??